# How to toggle animation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have an animation which works fine. But I can't reverse it. Can someone please give me a hint?

```
$(".arrowclose").click(function() {
    $(".arrow").animate({ left: "218px" }, 1000, "easeOutQuad");                
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".arrow").addClass("arrow_right arrowopen");
        $(".arrow").removeClass("arrow_left arrowclose");
}, 1000);
});

$(".arrowopen").click(function() {
    $(".arrow").animate({ left: "486px" }, 1000, "easeOutQuad");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".arrow").addClass("arrow_left arrowclose");
        $(".arrow").removeClass("arrow_right arrowopen");
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: You know you have a syntax error (missing the `}, time)`) in the first call to `animate()` right?

Comment: Sory wrong copy&paste. It's the same like in teh secons animation. I changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/opujov/2/edit)**</kbd>

Give this a try and get rid of unneeded classes

```
$(".arrow").click(function() {     
   $(this).stop().animate({ left: $(this).offset().left > 218 ? 218 : 486 }, 1000, "easeOutQuad", function() {
       $(this).toggleClass("arrowopen, arrowclose");
   });
});
```

**EDIT**

So far I understood you want an arrow that will toggle a container in-out so you might want this:

<kbd>**[jsBin demo 2](http://jsbin.com/opujov/7/edit)**</kbd>

Put the arrow INSIDE the container:

```
  <div class="wrapcontent">
    Test
    <div class="arrow arrowopen"></div>
  </div>
```

Style accordingly:

```
.arrowopen{
  position:absolute;
  right:-20px;
  top:0px;
  cursor:pointer;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}
.arrowopen  {background:#cf5;}
.arrowclose {background:#f00;}

.wrapcontent {

 position:absolute;
 width: 300px;
 height:100px;
 background:#888;
 left:-300px;

}
```

And on arrow -> click animate the parent container:

```
$(".arrow").click(function() {  

   $wrapcontent = $(this).closest('.wrapcontent');
   wrapOffset = $wrapcontent.offset().left;

   $wrapcontent.stop().animate({ left: !wrapOffset ? -300 : 0 }, 1000, "easeOutQuad");
   $(this).toggleClass("arrowopen, arrowclose");

});
```

Comment: That's perfect! And can I Use this also in combination? for example if I wanted to fade the .content layer out?

Comment: @mee sure, you can do whatever you want. Added a demo in the answer

Comment: But how can I add another div? for example to ,ove the content also a side? I tryed like this:

$(".arrow").click(function() {     
   $(this).stop().animate({ left: $(this).offset().left > 218 ? 218 : 486 }, 1000, "easeOutQuad", function() {
       $(this).toggleClass("arrow_links arrow_right");
   });
   
   $(".wrapcontent").animate({
       $(this).stop().animate({ left: $(this).offset().left > 112 ? 112 : 380 }, 1000, "easeOutQuad");
   
   $(".language, .maincontent, .footer").animate({
       opacity: "toggle",
   }, 500, "easeOutQuad");
});

Comment: @mee drop a jsBin demo link, and you're missing  a comma in your code: `"arrow_links, arrow_right"`

Comment: OK the code is not so helpfull … Well I tryed after you an addition new layer. But I diden't get it …

Comment: Drop me a link I'll take a look soon as I came back. have to run now

Comment: Thanks for the help. But you se the wrapcontent element is already there. Must I use another content rather the change the width?
What I like a sidebar left to drag out and back.

Comment: Ah OK, I understand it. Thanks for the help. I think I have to rebuild my structure ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using click event on element which doesn't exist on DOM ready (your arrowopen class). You should use .on() jQuery method -> http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".arrowclose").click(function() {
   $(".arrow").animate({
        left: "218px"
      }, 1000, "easeOutQuad",function(){
        $(".arrow").addClass("arrow_right arrowopen").removeClass("arrow_left arrowclose");
    });
});


$(".arrowopen").click(function() {
    $(".arrow").animate({
        left: "486px"
    }, 1000, "easeOutQuad", function(){
       $(".arrow").addClass("arrow_left arrowclose").removeClass("arrow_right arrowopen");
    });
});
```

Try this out and see if helps.

Comment: That's the same like in my script. It does the first animation but not back again.